# init.d doesn't get executed

Tags: boot, scripts, init.d

i am using samsung s2 and a custom rom, external sd card is mounted to /emmc but i want it to mount to /mnt/sdcard/external_sd, how could i mount it using init.d?

i made a file called "99mount" with a the content

```
mount -o bind /emmc /mnt/sdcard/external_sd
```

however, it isn't being executed an start tried also

```
busybox mount -o bind /emmc /mnt/sdcard/external_sd
```

and no luck, do i need to add 99mount to some xx.rc file?

Comment: Would creating a symbolic link from `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd` to `/emmc` work for your purposes?

Answer (score 3):

Your SD card isn't prepared at the time that the bind command is executed, because the mounting process hasn't ended yet. To bind, you have to wait several seconds for the mounting of SD card & external SD to be finished.

```
#!system/bin/sh    
sleep 10    
n="$(dumpsys mount | grep -c 'external')"    
until [ $n -eq 1 ]    
do    
sleep 1    
n="$(dumpsys mount | grep -c 'external')"    
done    
mount -o bind source target
```

**Note:** n="??" is changeable by according to your own system.